# json_encode combined with $_GET (PHP & Javascript)

Tags: php, javascript, json, getmethod

I need to pass a JSON array into a webpage URL so I do

```
$url = 'page.php?id=' . json_encode($array);
```

which becames

```
$url = 'pages.php?id=["1", "2", "3"]';
```

And then, inside `page.php` which is basically Javascript code  i do

`var foo = <?php $_GET['id']; ?>`

But `foo` instead of being an array like `["1", "2", "3"]` it's only `[`.

Why is this?

Also, is it better to do: `url.php?id=value` or `url.php?id="value"`??

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) it.

```
$url = 'page.php?id=' . urlencode(json_encode($array));
```

And don't forget to `json_decode()` it when it gets back.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But urlencode does this `[\"1\", \"2\", \"3\"]` which cannot then be read by Javascript

Comment: Use the code he suggests, then, inside `page.php` you'll want `var foo = <?php echo json_decode(urldecode($_GET['id'])); ?>`

Comment: @GEorge: No, that's your settings in php.ini.

Comment: @Ignacio, I uses str_replace to make `\"` to `"` and now it works .. But how about my second question: `Also, is it better to do: url.php?id=value or url.php?id="value"??`

Comment: @GEorge: There is no "better". Either you want to have those quotation marks being part of the value or not. You don't need them if that is your question. The value of `id` are the characters from the `=` to the next `&` or the end of the URL. The `"` have no special meaning and would just be part of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity do you have to pass it as a json_encoded string?

Perhaps you could pass it as an array

```
page.php?id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3
```

then your page.php code would look like this:

```
echo json_encode($_GET['id']);
```

I would also check for bad data using a white list approach if your passing in page ids.

```
$safe = array('1','2','3');
$id = $_GET['id'];
foreach($id as $value){
 if(!in_array($value, $safe)){
    echo "Sry, data not valid";
    exit;
 }
}
echo json_encode($id);
```